# Remove a tag within a tag in BeautifulSoap

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this BeautifulSoap code

```
title_box = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'descTitle'})
print title_box
```

which gives the following output

```
<span class="descTitle"> <a class="descTitle" href="/foo/bar"</a> | Quick Brown Fox!</span>
```

I would like to completely remove the `<a>` tag in it so I get the following output

```
<span class="descTitle"> | Quick Brown Fox!</span>
```

And after stripping text, my desired output is `Quick Brown Fox!` alone. Any ideas how I can also remove `|` before or after using `text.strip()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.text.strip().lstrip("|")`

**Ex:**

```
title_box = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'descTitle'}).text.strip().lstrip("|")
```

---

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<span class="descTitle"> <a class="descTitle" href="/foo/bar"</a> | Quick Brown Fox!</span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.find('span').text.strip().lstrip("|"))
# -->  Quick Brown Fox!
```

---